# How to refactor nested loops in a Ruby method that exports to CSV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, refactoring

I have to export some information to CSV. I wrote this code and I don't really like it. I don't know how I can refactor it and get rid of the nested loops.

My relations are the following: Order has many Moves, Move has many Stops.

I have to export all of this to CSV, so I will have multiple lines for the same order.

Here is my (low quality) code:

```
def to_csv
  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << h.t(self.first.exported_attributes.values.flatten) # headers
    self.each do |order|
      order.moves.map do |move|
        move.stops.map do |stop|
          order_data = order.exported_attributes[:order].map do |attributes|
            order.public_send(attributes)
          end
          move_data = order.exported_attributes[:move].map do |attributes|
            move.decorate.public_send(attributes)
          end
          stop_data = order.exported_attributes[:stop].map do |attributes|
            stop.decorate.public_send(attributes)
          end
          csv << order_data + move_data + stop_data
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I did this yesterday:

```
  def to_csv
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << h.t(self.first.exported_attributes.values.flatten) # headers
      self.each do |order|
        order.moves.each do |move|
          move.stops.each do |stop|
            csv << order.exported_attributes[:order].map { |attr| order.public_send(attr) } +
              order.exported_attributes[:move].map { |attr| move.decorate.send(attr) } +
              order.exported_attributes[:stop].map { |attr| stop.decorate.send(attr) }
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: in ruby, when you have a *one liner loop* it is recomended to **not** use *do ..end* cycle, instead use *{ }*. Example: `order_data = order.exported_attributes[:order].map { |attributes| order.public_send(attributes) }`. Just by doing this you went from 3 lines to 1 line.

Comment: *except when the one-liner is long and becomes (even) hard(er) to read like in the example above.

Comment: @user181452 can you provide some sample data? It is hard to guess what's the purpose of the start, move things above there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest smell I smell isn't the nested loops, but the near-duplication of how the values are gotten from each model.

Let's extract that duplication into similar methods with the same name, `exported_values`, on `Order`, `Move` and `Stop`:

```
class Order
  def exported_values
    exported_attributes[:order].map { |attrs| { public_send(attrs) }
  end
end

class Move
  def exported_values
    order.exported_attributes[:stop].map { |attrs| { decorate.public_send(attrs) }
  end
end

class Stop
  def exported_values
    move.order.exported_attributes[:move].map { |attrs| { decorate.public_send(attrs) }
  end
end
```

and use them in `to_csv`:

```
def to_csv
  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << h.t(first.exported_attributes.values.flatten) # headers
    each do |order|
      order_values = order.exported_values
      order.moves.each do |move|
        order_and_move_values = order_values + move.exported_values
        move.stops.each do |stop|
          csv << order_and_move_values + stop.exported_values
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The above has some additional minor improvements:

- Get and concatenate the exported values in the outermost possible loops for efficiency.
- Loop over moves and stops with `each` rather than with `map`, since the loops are done for side effects rather than return values.
- Remove unnecessary uses of `self.`.

Now `to_csv` isn't so bad. But it still has a little [feature envy](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FeatureEnvySmell) (that is, it calls too many methods on other objects), so let's extract more methods onto the models:

```
def to_csv
  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << h.t(first.exported_attributes.values.flatten) # headers
    each { |order| order.append_to_csv(csv) }
  end
end

class Order
  def append_to_csv(csv)
    values = exported_values
    moves.each { |move| move.append_to_csv(csv, values) }
  end
end

class Move
  def append_to_csv(csv, prefix)
    values = exported_values
    stops.each { |stop| stop.append_to_csv(csv, prefix + values) }
  end
end

class Stop
  def append_to_csv(csv, prefix)
    csv << prefix + exported_values
  end
end
```

No more nested loops. The extracted methods are a bit duplicative, but I think if the duplication were extracted they would be unclear.

Next we could try to refactor the `exported_values` methods into a single method.

- Perhaps `Order#exported_attributes` could be broken up into a method on each class that takes no arguments and returns only that class's exported attributes.
- The other difference between the methods is that `Order` doesn't need `.decorator` but the other classes do. If it has a decorator, just use that instead of the actual order; if not, just give it a fake one:

  ```
  class Order
    def decorator
      self
    end
  end
  ```

You could then define a single `exported_values` method in an module and include it in all three classes:

```
def exported_values
  exported_attributes.map { |attrs| { decorator.public_send(attrs) }
end
```

There is one more possible improvement: if it was OK for each model's exported values to remain the same for the lifetime of an instance, you could cache them like this

```
def exported_values
  @exported_values ||= exported_attributes.map { |attrs| { decorator.public_send(attrs) }
end
```

and inline the `values` locals in the `append_to_csv` methods *and* get the "prefixes" from parent objects in those methods instead of passing them as parameters.

Possibly all of the new methods should be extracted to the decorators rather than to the models; I'm not sure whether your decorators are for CSV generation or only for other purposes.

Comment: Thank you so much ! brilliant, I'm now doing the refactoring, we're using Draper gem, I put `exported_values ` in the parent decorator and `exported_attributes ` defined in each decorator. 
still trying to make it work `exported_values ` because it worked for the order but not for the move, because the send should be called on object

Comment: I took one more pass. See what you think.

Comment: I like it, thanks. will stick to the first solution for now, I added it in my question. and I will add more refactor later.

I have a question, now I have export only few attributes from each decorator, this will kind of ruin my structure, and I don't like to repeat it all for this special export :/ 
can I use the old one in your opinion ?

Comment: No, I wouldn't export more attributes for the sake of this refactoring. I'd put the CSV construction code in the decorators but get the attributes from the wrapped models.

Comment: no, the old export is for "all attributes", I have to add another export to "fewer attributes" and my method depend of `exported attributes` method, so I have to write two new methods for that, I don't feel that's right, maybe passing the array of attributes to `exported_values` would be better ?